# cannot put the Button in center position by widget class initialziation

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to initialize the widget class by placing a button at the root.center. Strangely, root.size during initialization is only (100,100).  When it's rendered, the actual size is (600,800). So my button is placed in the left bottom instead of in the center.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

w = Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Button:
        id: score_button
        center: root.score_button_center
        text:'Best Scores'
''')


class MyWidget(Widget):

    score_center_y = NumericProperty(-100)
    score_center_x = NumericProperty(-100)
    score_button_center = ReferenceListProperty(score_center_x, score_center_y)
    hide_center = (-100, -100)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.score_button_center = self.width, self.height


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        g = MyWidget()
        return g


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
center: root.score_button_center
```

to:

```
center: root.center
```

That will take advantage of the kivy feature that sets up bindings to adjust the Button position whenever the root widget changes size or position.

Comment: I don't want to fix it in the center. I want to be able to move the button around. This would be a score button where player can click and see the top scores when the game is not played. And I want to hide the button when the game is being played.

Comment: How do you want to move it?

Comment: change its center property to the hide_center

Comment: I think you can just use `self.ids.score_button.center = self.hide_center` in a method of `MyWidget`.

Comment: the problem is not hiding it. It's that i cannot initilialize it by putting it in the middle. It would appear on the left bottom